# signature.verify() is returning false in java

Tags: java, security, rsa, digital-signature, sha1

First of all, I see there are other posts with this question, but no one has the same problem as me, i.e. `signature.verify()` is unexpectedly returning `false`.

Here's my code:

```
private static String encriptar(String xmlSolicitud, PrivateKey privateKey)
        throws Exception {

    Signature signature=Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(xmlSolicitud.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    byte[] signatureValue = signature.sign();
    String response = Base64.encode(signatureValue);
    signature.initVerify(keyReader.publicKeyRead(Reference.rutaPublicKeyTest));
    System.out.println(signature.verify(signatureValue));
    return response;
}
```

And here is how I read in the keys (if needed):

```
public static PrivateKey privateKeyRead(String filename)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec =
                new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
}

public static PublicKey publicKeyRead(String filename)
        throws Exception {

    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
                new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117526/unable-to-verify-signed-xml-with-certificate-cer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of the signature is reset after you call `sign`. As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#sign()):

> A call to this method resets this signature object to the state it was
>   in when previously initialized for signing via a call to
>   `initSign(PrivateKey)`. That is, the object is reset and available to
>   generate another signature from the same signer, if desired, via new
>   calls to `update` and `sign`.

You need to update the signature again with the bytes that were signed:

```
private static String encriptar(String xmlSolicitud, PrivateKey privateKey)
        throws Exception {

    Signature signature=Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(xmlSolicitud.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    byte[] signatureValue = signature.sign();
    String response = Base64.encode(signatureValue);

    signature.initVerify(keyReader.publicKeyRead(Reference.rutaPublicKeyTest));
    signature.update(xmlSolicitud.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); // <-- Here

    System.out.println(signature.verify(signatureValue)); // <-- Will print true

    return response;
}
```

---

On a side note, it looks like you're signing XML content. Probably wise to use [XML signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature) to avoid being tripped up by canonicalization issues.

Comment: Wow, thanks, it works! And thank you for the text corrections!.
The WebService is still returning a invalid CMS error, but it should be another bug.
thank you very much!

Comment: XML signatures looks nice, but i'm not sure, I'm really noob with xml, but any WebService should understand it? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously it depends on the service, but generally speaking a web service that requires signed XML content will in most cases be expecting an XML signature.

Comment: Well, maybe that's why i'm getting that error, I will take a look.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Here String *xmlSolicitud* means entire XML or only signature node in XML?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you tell what I'm doing wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117526/unable-to-verify-signed-xml-with-certificate-cer

Comment: @moDev See the final part of my answer. You're attempting to verify an XML signature (XML-DSig). There is *a lot* more involved than what you're doing in your code. I'm afraid that I currently don't have the time to write up a complete answer for you. Google something like "XML-DSig validation in Java" to get started.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ok, I need to understand the steps.1. Public Key 2. Update data in signature and 3. Verify. Do we need to encode xml data in step 2?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'm not able to get proper solution

Comment: can you suggest or share any online tool where I can validate this process? Thank you!